# Wait future completion to execute a another one for a sequence

Tags: scala, future

I met a read / write problem this last days and I cannot fix an issue in my test. I have a JSON document based on the following model

```
package models 

import play.api.libs.json._

object Models {

  case class Record
  (
    id : Int, 
    samples : List[Double]
  )

  object Record {
    implicit val recordFormat = Json.format[Record]
  }
}
```

I have two functions : one to read a record and an another one to update.

```
case class MongoIO(futureCollection : Future[JSONCollection]) {

  def readRecord(id : Int) : Future[Option[Record]] = 
    futureCollection
      .flatMap { collection =>
      collection.find(Json.obj("id" -> id)).one[Record]
    }

  def updateRecord(id : Int, newSample : Double) : Future[UpdateWriteResult]= {
    readRecord(id) flatMap { recordOpt =>
      recordOpt match {
        case None =>
          Future { UpdateWriteResult(ok = false, -1, -1, Seq(), Seq(), None, None, None) }
        case Some(record) =>
          val newRecord = 
            record.copy(samples = record.samples :+ newSample)
          futureCollection
          .flatMap { collection =>
            collection.update(Json.obj("id" -> id), newRecord)
          }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now, I have a `List[Future[UpdateWriteResult]]` corresponds to a many updates on the document but what I want is that : wait the future is complete to execute the second one then wait the completion of the second to execute the third. I tried to do that with a `foldLeft and flatMap` like this :

```
val l : List[Future[UpdateWriteResult]] = ...
println(l.size) // give me 10
l
.foldLeft(Future.successful(UpdateWriteResult(ok = false, -1, -1, Seq(), Seq(), None, None, None))) { 
     case (cur, next) => cur.flatMap(_ => next)
  }
```

but the document is never updated like excepted : instead to have a document with a samples list of size 10, I got a list of 1 samples. So the read is faster than the write (impression that I have) and also using a combinaison of `foldLeft / flatMap` seems to do not wait the completion of the current future so how can I fix this issue properly (without Await) ?

### Update

```
val futureCollection = DB.getCollection("foo")
val mongoIO = MongoIO(futureCollection)
val id = 1
val samples = List(1.1, 2.2, 3.3)
val l : List[Future[UpdateWriteResult]] = samples.map(sample => mongoIO.updateRecord(id, sample))
```

Comment: Have you tried using `Future.sequence(...)`?

Comment: Futures are triggered when you instantiate them. By the time you have a `List[Future[...]]` it is too late to try to control the order in which they get executed. If you want to control that, you have to do it before they get instantiated.

Comment: @Jean-PhilippePellet I tried but same result.

Comment: @AlvaroCarrasco How I can control like excepted the futures to be execute ?

Comment: @Jean-PhilippePellet `Future.sequence` has no effect on the order of execution (once they've been triggered). @alifirat Post the code tha produces the `List[Future[...]]`

Comment: @AlvaroCarrasco code posted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to do the `foldLeft` on the `samples`:

```
(mongoIO.updateRecord(id, samples.head) /: samples.tail) {(acc, next) =>
  acc.flatMap(_ => mongoIO.updateRecord(id, next))
}
```

`updateRecord` is what triggers the future, so you have to make sure **not to call it** until the previous one finishes.

Answer (score 1):

I took the liberty of making some minor modification to you original sources:

```
case class MongoIO(futureCollection : Future[JSONCollection]) {

  def readRecord(id : Int) : Future[Option[Record]] = 
    futureCollection.flatMap(_.find(Json.obj("id" -> id)).one[Record])

  def updateRecord(id : Int, newSample : Double) : Future[UpdateWriteResult] =
    readRecord(id) flatMap {
      case None => Future.successful(UpdateWriteResult(ok = false, -1, -1, Nil, Nil, None, None, None))
      case Some(record) =>
        val newRecord = record.copy(samples = record.samples :+ newSample)
        futureCollection.flatMap(_.update(Json.obj("id" -> id), newRecord))
    }
}
```

Then we only need to write a serialized/sequential update:

```
def update(samples: Seq[Double], id: Int): Future[Unit] = s match {
  case sample +: remainingSamples => updateRecord(id, sample).flatMap(_ => update(remainingSamples, id))
  case _ => Future.successful(())
}
```

Comment: What does that mean?

Comment: s should be a `List[Double]` instead to be a `List[UpdateWriteResult]`.